# POST /420 Message is Showing on Cypress

Tags: api, automation, cypress, http-status-code-422

Recently I have started with Cypress with visual studio code and there is one step where I am doing sign up and User should be navigated to URL/account but what I can see response in terminal is 
"POST /signup 422" message for only that particular step.

But when I manually do the registration of user it is navigating to account page successfully

Is there anyone who got same kind of situation?
Editor: VS
Lang: JS
Cypress automation : cypress version 4

Comment: I am guessing it to be synchronization. Did you try adding some delay before you try to navigate to URL/account after signup?

Comment: actually I am adding user details and clicking on signup button, then it should navigate to "URL/account" but still was in "URL/signup" page.

Same when I do manually it is happening perfectly as expected